# Spring Data Neo4j return count of affected nodes after update operation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Is there any way to return the count of affected nodes after doing the update operation with Spring Data Neo4j repository?

e.g

```
@Query("MATCH (n:Student) WHERE n.id IN $idList SET n.isRegistered = true")
Integer updateRegisterInfo(@Param("idList") List<String> idList);
```

But sdn can only return void/null value for such operation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want the count of nodes to which the `SET` was applied, return the count of rows:

```sql
MATCH (n:Student) WHERE n.id IN $idList 
SET n.isRegistered = true
RETURN count(*) AS numAffected
```

If you want the count of nodes whose value of `isRegistered` was changed, remove nodes that already have `isRegistered = true` with the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
MATCH (n:Student) 
WHERE n.id IN $idList AND NOT coalesce(n.isRegistered, false) 
SET n.isRegistered = true
RETURN count(*) AS numAffected
```

(I've just formatted as stand-alone Cypher to make it easier read.)

Comment: But the above query is counting the number of nodes before the `SET` operation is done, right? What I actually want is to get the number of nodes that are updated after the `SET` operation. For example, if the input is 3 and somehow the nodes are successfully updated is 2, the sdn should return 2 instead of the size of input.

Comment: The first query returns the number of nodes for which `SET` was _invoked_. The second returns the number of nodes where the value has been _changed_.

Comment: After executing the query through java driver it returns a result object where you can get resultSummary which contains the no of nodes that got updated, created on executing the query. In similar fashion can you check if those are available in spring?

For Reference:
https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org.neo4j.driver/org/neo4j/driver/Result.html

https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org.neo4j.driver/org/neo4j/driver/summary/ResultSummary.htmlw

https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org.neo4j.driver/org/neo4j/driver/summary/SummaryCounters.html